# Possible to ssh to remote Pi inside corporate firewall without port-forwarding?

Tags: networking, ssh, remote, port-forwarding

**Situation** :: There's a Pi running an arcade machine inside a clients' office. I can connect to a network via utp cable, so the Pi has internet connection, but asking for port forwarding to ssh to the Pi is not an option. I would like to be able to ssh it though.

**Question** :: Is there an option to do it via some sort of tunnel or third party software? Could the Pi itself make some sort of connection outside and would I be able to use that? I do have a 24/7-on Linux box at home and in the cloud on which I can install software.

Comment: Bypassing corporate security to play games is a good way to get fired. Something that your question implies you already know. By yourself a Pi and run it at home - and if IT did not put the Pi on the network remove it.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to connect to this pi for reasons other than playing games (why would you play arcade games on a clients raspberry pi over the internet, makes no sense at all as it would be unplayable) - maybe a simple *reverse SSH tunnel* is what you need

Comment: Indeed as JaromandaX said @SteveRobillard, I'm not going to play it, that would be a very silly way indeed. The arcade cabinet runs a tailormade marketing game created for the customer. Sometimes there are updated, so it's then necessary to ssh to the machine. At the moment this is done physically by going to the client and connecting a laptop to the pi by x-ftp cable.

Comment: Oh, and I'm from The Netherlands. We don't get fired for playing games during work. We are encouraged to, it's good for general health and thus productivity ;-)

Comment: How in the world do you expect anyone here to know your client's networking arrangements; i.e. **how** your client has his firewall/border router(s) configured - what's permitted, what's blocked, etc, etc??? This is a foolish and pointless question - you should delete it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a foolish and pointless question.

Comment: @Seamus Care to explain why this is a foolish question? Why is this situation so hard to imagine? We create custom games for customers that they have running on a tailormade arcade cabinet in their cantine. And as Pi's do, sometimes they crash, sometimes we have updates, and we thus have to connect to the box (that could be in another city, or even country for that matter).

Comment: It is exactly because what you say that I ask this question. Is it possible to create some sort of connection through a web connection without having to know about customers network? Most of the times the one at the customer doesn't know anything about their networking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/).

I am not trained in network administration, everyone is welcome to improve my terminology. ZT is, if I understand correctly, a virtual private network. ZT client (i.e. the software) is [available](https://www.zerotier.com/download/) on Linux systems bare-metal and via docker.

1. [Create a profile and a network](https://my.zerotier.com/)
2. [Add, and authorize the client's pi and your Linux box](https://docs.zerotier.com/start) to the network created in Step 1.
3. Profit $$$, i.e., devices can `ping` and `ssh` each other!